# How To Check Server or Ip Address available/connected in Android

Tags: java, android, networking, connection, android-networking

How to Know server/ip address is available / connected in android.
I try this code

```
final EditText ed_ip = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ed_server);
Button btn_ip_save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_save_ip);

btn_ip_save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

String str_serverip = ed_ip.getText().toString();
int timeout = 2000;

byte [] b = str_serverip.getBytes();

boolean addr = InetAddress.getByAddress(b).isReachable(timeout);

if(addr == true)
{
       txt.setText("Response");
      Toast.makeText(IpConfig.this, "Reachable", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}else {

    txt.setText("Not Response");
    Toast.makeText(IpConfig.this, "Not", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
```

its always refuse connection except 127.0.0.1

How to check plz guide me ..

Comment: Try these two: 

 1. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905358/how-to-ping-external-ip-from-java-android
 2. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584210/preferred-java-way-to-ping-a-http-url-for-availability

Comment: i do it but give same error to me