# How to test the availability of WSDL programmatically using Java

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

This means i would NOT use SoapUI, or any other Application to test the WSDL.

i am looking at [wsdl4j](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsdl4j/) as this is potentially the only one out there, unless i am missing something available in jdk.

Here is what i tried:

class : WSDLtestvip.java

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class WSDLtestvip {



    public boolean isWSDLAvailable(String wsdlAddr) {
        HttpURLConnection c = null;
        try {
            URL u = new URL(wsdlAddr);
            c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
            c.getInputStream();
            return c.getResponseCode() == 200;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (c != null)
                c.disconnect();
        }

    }
}
```

class: WsdlTester.java

```
public class WsdlTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WSDLtestvip wstvip = new WSDLtestvip();
        boolean result = wstvip
                .isWSDLAvailable("https://a.b.c/aaa?wsdl");

        System.out.println(result);

    }

}
```

and it gives me false ALL the time
How can i use the same for https

Comment: Did you really mean "problematically" or is it programmatically?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584210/preferred-java-way-to-ping-a-http-url-for-availability

Comment: programmatically, was correcting spelling and look what i got. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suggestion:

```
    private boolean isWSDLAvailable(String wsdlAddr) {
            HttpURLConnection c = null;
            try {
                URL u = new URL(wsdlAddr);
                c = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                c.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
                c.getInputStream();
                return c.getResponseCode() == 200;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return false;
            } finally {
                if (c != null) c.disconnect();
            }    
    }
```

And you can check content-type too, if needed.

Comment: What about HTTPS, i tried the same code with https, and got "False" returned.

Comment: Check Exception message. If this is a self-signed certificate, [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859111/how-do-i-accept-a-self-signed-certificate-with-a-java-httpsurlconnection) can be useful.

Comment: (...) catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e); return false; (...)

Comment: Why not just use `GET`? Some platforms (Spring-WS) will return `405 Method Not Allowed` in response to `HEAD`.