# Android How to check URL name or IP is rechable

Tags: android, url, inetaddress

My code is as follow:

```
public chkRechable(String hostNameOrIp) {

boolean isRechable = InetAddress.getByName(hostNameOrIp).isReachable(30);
return isRechable;
}
```

Parameter can be `"http://192.168.0.77:8080/ws/api/customer/5"` or `"http://example.com:8080/ws/api/customer/5"`

But everytime it's returning false although I can browse the URL.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `getByAddress` instead of `getByName` for an IP Address? And see if the solution here works: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3584332/450534

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean "reachable"?
If "open the page" means "reachable", you can just try to use an HTTP connection to connect to it. If you got exceptions: your net work might down; you cannot connect to the host;
Then you shall check the http return code, to see if there are 404 or other errors.