# Testing if a URL is Valid

Tags: java, url

I have many URLs want to create a program that will see if the URL can be connected to and loaded.

I was thinking I could try downloading the source, but if it isn't a site then it wont download it. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

EDIT: I'm going to use a HttpURLConnection and was wondering what method is fastest.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

Is post or get better, and why?

Comment: Possible duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/q/3584210/2040040

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check syntax, the [URL](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html)'s constructor will address it. If you want to check for connectivity:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
try {
    connection.setMethod("GET");
    connection.connect();
} catch (IOException e) {
try {
    connection.setMethod("POST");
    connection.connect();
} catch (IOException e) {
try {
    connection.setMethod("HEAD");
    connection.connect();
} catch (IOException e) { try {
    connection.setMethod("DELETE");
    connection.connect();
}}}} catch (IOException e) {
// failed
}
```