# Lotus Notes Java Agent cannot connect to alive server

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus, urlconnection, agent

I'm trying to do a HTTP request from a Java agent in Lotus Notes, to an IP address on our network. I have tried exactly the same code in Eclipse and the request is made successfully.

```
URL url = new URL(u);
URLConnection urlConnect = url.openConnection();
```

urlConnect is null.

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:719)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:646)
at COM.ibm.JEmpower.applet.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:411)
at java.net.URLConnection.getContent(URLConnection.java:712)
at JavaAgent.NotesMain(JavaAgent.java:25)
at lotus.domino.AgentBase.runNotes(Unknown Source)
at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: What version of java?

Comment: Permission problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/20706068/2065611?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise there were further restrictions other than the settings in the Agent dialog, I'll contact out IT support team.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java NullPointerException in Java Agent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20696245/java-nullpointerexception-in-java-agent)