# Check Internet Connection in Android (Not connection State)

Tags: android, http-post, httprequest, http-get

I need help to check if there's a connection to some given URL to make sure i have a connection to the internet.

I've used this code:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
```

but it's not so helpful, cause the device may be connected to WiFi or Mobile network but there's no connection to the internet.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can ping a website for checking if Internet is available. You can ping google.com, mostly online.

```
public static boolean ping(String url, int timeout) {
    url = url.replaceFirst("https", "http"); // Otherwise an exception may be thrown on invalid SSL certificates.

    try {
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        connection.setReadTimeout(timeout);
        connection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        return (200 <= responseCode && responseCode <= 399);
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

taken from here [Preferred Java way to ping an HTTP URL for availability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584210/preferred-java-way-to-ping-a-http-url-for-availability)

Comment: yup yup it works now, i used to put "http://www.google.com" in the url string, but i changed it to "google.com" and it works great now. Thanks a lot

Comment: I figured now that it always returns false!, why so?!