# How to check the connection status of a Kinesis client?

Tags: amazon-kinesis

I run a fleet of web services behind a load balancer. The lb periodically requests a status endpoint to verify that the particular server is operational. This service endpoint checks connectivity to all external services (sql, redis, kinesis etc.)

To check the kinesis connectivity I originally used `kinesis.listStreams()` but as we are increasing the number of servers we are running into the 5 req/sec [limit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/service-sizes-and-limits.html) of the listStreams command.

What is the best/cheapest way to verify that kinesis is available?

We are using the Java client, but I imagine it would be the same for all clients.

Answer (score 1):

AWS support answered in this thread https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=743149&#743149

Kinesis does not directly support this.

There are two options:

1) Perform the rate limited request and treat the rate limit exception as a success as it being returned by the server indicates that the connection is working.

> The rate limiting in this case is actually done on the server side. So
>   you will either get a valid ListStreams response (HTTP code 200), or
>   you'll get a LimitExceededException (HTTP code 400). Both responses
>   imply that you have connectivity to the Kinesis endpoint, since the
>   response is coming from the service. If connectivity is broken, you
>   would see timeouts or other errors with response code 5xx (things like
>   ServiceUnavailableException).

2) Don't use the kinesis library, but use regular network techniques to test connectivity to the kinesis rest endpoint

> Unfortunately (and for obvious reasons), all our APIs are rate limited
>   and we don't expose any APIs suitable for this usage pattern. However,
>   it seems like you just want to verify the connectivity between your
>   service and the Kinesis endpoint. You don't really need to use the AWS
>   SDK for this, you can probably use standard Java libraries to perform
>   something like a "ping" to our endpoint. 
>   [Preferred Java way to ping an HTTP URL for availability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584210/preferred-java-way-to-ping-an-http-url-for-availability)
>   has some options