# How do you find out if url exist before trying to load it in webview in javafx?

Tags: javafx, webview

So i'm trying to figure out if you can see if a web site exist and  if its https or http before try to load it in javafx webview

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584210/preferred-java-way-to-ping-an-http-url-for-availability