# How to check if the url is there or not in java?

Tags: java

I am coming to an issue where I need help to check for a url that when I search on a particular `code` it wont show the url that I have listed. Is there a way to make it work with my code? I tried and created a method below which is `generateLink`. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you asking how to check whether a URL is reachable?  What does “it wont show the url” mean?  What, exactly, won’t show the URL?  What do you want your `generateLink` method to do if the URL is not reachable?  Should it return `null`?

Comment: yes, I meant to be reachable. yes, I want my method to do if the URL is not reachable and yes to return null based on the `jobClassCd`

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584210/preferred-java-way-to-ping-an-http-url-for-availability

Comment: Generally, your program should attempt to connect to the given URL and catch the return code i.e. 404 if unavailable, and process your logic from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, since `generateLink` will either return a valid URL or `null`, you need to change this:

```
jgen.writeStringField("pay_grade_description_link", generateLink(XXX_URL + value.jobClassCd) + ".pdf");
```

to this:

```
jgen.writeStringField("pay_grade_description_link", generateLink(value.jobClassCd));
```

If you concatenate ".pdf" to it, null return values will be meaningless, since `null + ".pdf"` results in the eight-character string `"null.pdf"`.

Second, you can check the response code of an HttpURLConnection to test a URL’s validity.  (In theory, you should be able to use the ["OPTIONS"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.2) HTTP method to test the URL, but not all servers support it.)

```
private String generateLink(String jobClassCd) {
    String url = XXX_URL + jobClassCd + ".pdf";
    try {
        HttpURLConnection connection =
            (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();

        if (connection.getResponseCode() < 400) {
            return url;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Logger.getLogger(JobSerializer.class.getName()).log(Level.FINE,
            "URL \"" + url + "\" is not reachable.", e);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But, I am getting error on `Level.FINE,` how can I import that properly?

Comment: Class `Logger` is java.util.logging.Logger.  Class `Level` is java.util.logging.Level.

Comment: You could, but it’s good practice to show the stack trace of any exception you catch, so if you don’t want to use a Logger, use `e.printStackTrace();`.  The nice thing about a Logger is that you can control how much it actually prints without having to change the code.